# Removing specific item in cart angular 10

Tags: angular

What am I missing here? I just want to delete the specific item but it's deleting the last item on my list if I have more than 1 item.

This is what I have on my service:

```
//cartService.ts

 removeItem(index){
      this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(index), 1); //this is the problem
  }
```

This is my component:

```
 //cartComponent.ts

removeItem(index) {
     this.cartService.removeItem(index);
}
```

And my html:

```
// cart.html 

<div  class="col-12 " *ngFor="let addedItem of items; let index = index  ">
  <ul>
     <li> {{addedItem.name }}  <button class="btn" (click)="removeItem(index)"> delete </button> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.items.indexOf(this.items)` this is wrong.you shouuld pass the item that you want to remove

Comment: You are actually not passing a specific item. You are trying to get Index of whole array this.items . I think that’s the problem. Try to pass the item or it’s index from ngFor and then use it in your service.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha  I knew that it was wrong. Even if I pass a specific item like: 

removeItem(index){
      this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(index), 1);
   }

or

removeItem(index){
      this.items.splice(index);
   }

still it removes the last one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following changes should work.

**HTML:**

```
<div  class="col-12 " *ngFor="let addedItem of items; let i = index ">
  <ul>
     <li> {{addedItem.name }}  <button class="btn" (click)="removeItem(i)"> delete </button> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**cartComponent.ts**

```
removeItem(index: number) {
     this.cartService.removeItem(index);
}
```

**cartService.ts**

```
removeItem(index: number){
      this.items.splice(index, 1);
  }
```